# Как вставить текст без стилей в QTextEdit в PyQt5?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы текст с различных сайтов при вставке в QTextEdit имел размер шрифта, выделение, цвет по умолчанию. То есть, чтобы не было так, как на скрине, а чтобы текст был чистый: черным по белому.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может просто использовать QPlainTextEdit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Варианты:

- Использовать метод [QTextEdit.setPlainText](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#setPlainText)
- Использовать вместо [QTextEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html) класс [QPlainTextEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html)

Comment: Благодарю, все работает.